# Apache Tomcat Redirect

Tags: apache, tomcat

I want to redirect http://localhost:8080/MyProject to http://localhost:8080/NewProject, but i dont have the "MyProject" folder in webapps anymore. Its a new project that have something in common with the other, but i still want to redirect the users that use the old URL to the new one.

I've tried something like this https://serverfault.com/questions/602275/redirect-url-to-a-tomcat-webapp, but it has nothing to do with what i want.

is there any simple way i can do this?

Comment: what is your deployment architecture ? do you have tomact behind apache? I mean to ask whether you are using apache as web server front facing tomcat?

Comment: Im just using Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 with the JVM 1.7.0_71-b14